# Order By in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to use orderby ASC with field name in this query :-

```
        $repository = $this->em->getRepository('XXXAbcBundle:BuilderPage');
    return $repository->findAll(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

How It's possible ?

I want the result set is hydrated into an array that represents the object graph in ASC order.

Comment: Check this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116888/how-to-sort-findall-doctrines-method

Comment: @PiotrKazulak Thanks for comment. I know this way but My question is How I can pass oder by in this function $repository->findAll(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need HYDRATE_ARRAY as an result then you can try this (this sort by BuilderPage.name ASC):

```
$repository = $this->em->getRepository('XXXAbcBundle:BuilderPage');
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('BuilderPage')
        ->select('BuilderPage')
        ->orderBy('BuilderPage.name', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery();

return $query->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Comment: Thanks , I can go this way but in other controller we didn't find array object where I used this function. So we return only $query->getResult()