# What files to edit in order to change the sort findAll function in Doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a particular table that I always want to have sorted in a specific way (say, the users table must be sorted by username, always).When I run this:

$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('User')->findAll();

I want the returned list to be ordered by username, without having to pass this every single time in the controller.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116888/how-to-sort-findall-doctrines-method#17120087), the way to implement this is by "defining your own query in the entity repository". I am new to Doctrine and not sure exactly where this should be done. Please note that I am not using Symfony, only the Doctrine ORM.

If I understand correctly, I have to set this up:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAll()
    {
        return $this->findBy(array(), array('username' => 'ASC'));
    }
}
```

My question is: in what file should I configure this? In which folder? I have found the original function in the main doctrine folder (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM), in a file called EntityRepository.php, but editing this file means that: a) changes will be overwritten upon updates to Doctrine, and b) this applies to ALL of my tables, not just to this one.